# Why does this ruby script fail to execute?

Tags: ruby, windows

I have this ruby script that is supposed to copy/rename a set of images, but it wont work for some reason. My experience with ruby is little so i wonder why it wont work.

Here is the script.

```
tile_width = 256
tile_height = 256
image_width = 1024
image_height = 6144
n = 0
# To get this number, look at the number of tiles 
# generated, find the last tile number and add 1
# e.g. tiles_99.png => total_tiles = 100
total_tiles = 256 

tiles_per_column = image_width/tile_width

row = 0
column = 0
(n...total_tiles).each do |i|
  filename = "tiles_#{i}.png" # current filename
  target = "map_#{column}_#{row}.png" # new filename

  puts "copy #{filename} to #{target}" 

  `cp -f #{filename} #{target}` # rename

  # work out next step
  column = column + 1
  if column >= tiles_per_column
    column = 0
    row = row + 1
  end
end
```

And here is the error which is returned

```
copy tiles_0.png to map_0_0.png
script.rb:21:in ``': No such file or directory - cp -f tiles_0.png map_0_0.png (Errno::ENOENT)
        from script.rb:21:in `block in <main>'
        from script.rb:15:in `each'
        from script.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

And here is the images i am trying to rename/copy

[image: Screenshot of image folder]

Comment: No reason to call out to the OS, but unless you're running cygwin or some other Unix-like utils, there's no such thing as `cp`, just like the error message says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you are running on windows so no `cp` command for you, use [`FileUtils::cp`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-cp) instead.

Put this at the top of your file:
`require 'fileutils'`

remove line 21 and put this code instead: `FileUtils.cp(filename, target)`

now it should work :)

Comment: That's it! Simply require FileUtils and doing `FileUtils.cp filename, target` solved my problem. Thanks!